# Detecting if an event happens multiple times in a short timespan

Tags: python

This might be a bit hard to explain, but I hope I can explain it in a sufficient and understandable way.

I want to create a system to detect if a large amount of users suddenly joins our server, but i'm not sure how this would be setup.

Should I store every single new user in Redis and a timestamp, and then with a background tasks every n seconds/minutes check if the amount of users in a timespan is larger than an estimate of new users that I know we get ?

So like

```
if new_user_count > 10:
    sendwarning()
```

But how would I incorporate and check within a certain timespan? Maybe the amount of new users since last scan?

Is this a sufficient way or is there some other smart method that I don't know of?

Answer (score 1):

when a user connects a server (depending upon what kind of server you have) say if you have a linux server every user connection to your server has a entry in (/var/log/<file.log>) location you can write a simple python program to monitor this file and put regex to count the user "successful login". You can also use opensource IDS(Intrusion Detection System) like Snort in your server to do the same for you.
https://www.snort.org/